# Is there a questionnaire that helps to take IMPLEMENTATION decisions in advance?

Tags: architecture, implementation

I was wondering if there is a well known questionnaire that you can walk through before taking implementation decisions upon a 'Requirements Documentation' ?

Basically a list of questions that needs yes/no answers so that you can more or less foresee your implementation road map.

Comment: +1 I have never seen one in twenty years, but it sounds interesting if there were such a thing.

Comment: +1 Good question - but I think the java and .net should be removed.

Comment: I don't want to create one by myself... As it would be very poor. I am very curious if it was done before by some experienced developers already.

Comment: that questionnaire might likely be the "Lifecycle Architecture Milestone" in RUP

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled upon something like this a while back.

http://gorban.org/post/32873465932/software-architecture-cheat-sheet

I think the points are spot on, and things i sometime forgets to ask myself when doing some architecture decisions.

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: it is an interesting list with general advice. i see the answer like something like this of a list with specific project or app domain advice.